# Cannot modify UV texture in the UV editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am following a blender guru's video, and I had some trouble adjusting the floor's UV. In the view port, the texture works fine, I just want to change the scale of it, but in the UV editor.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Enter Edit mode for the object and select all geometry

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate UV on the image you need to:

1. Unwrap your model.
2. Copy image name from texture node by Ctrl+C.
3. Find it in dropdown menu of image area.

[image: uv unwrap]